# How to send custom iMessage view with JSON data and possibility to open it in my app?

Tags: ios, json, imessage, imessage-extension

I have an app. And now I would like to share the data from one user to another via iMessage app and custom messages like this:

[image]

What I need to achieve?

- share some JSON content and open it in my app if it is installed on iPhone...
- JSON data should be sent from within an app directly...

**is it possible?**

Comment: You can send custom data in imessage using message compose delegate message, if you want to open specific screen of your installed app then you can do it by sending deeplink url of your installed app.